# Print the length of words as input as a histogram with horizontal bars

Tags: strings, ruby, functional-programming, ascii-art

**Input**

A list of words separated by any number of spaces.

**Output**

A horizontal ASCII art histogram, where the n-th line is composed by as many asterisks (`*`) as the n-th word is long.

**Example usage**

The `>` signals user input, you should not input it when testing the program.

```
> This is an example histogram of word length
****
**
**
*******
*********
**
****
******
```

---

```
> a aa aaa aaaa aaaaa
*
**
***
****
*****
```

---

```
> double space  example
******
*****
*******
```

**The code**

```
puts gets.chomp.split.map{|word| '*' * word.length}.join("\n")
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks good. There's really not a lot to review. About the only thing I can think of is that I'd like a little breathing space in the block, i.e.

```
{ |word| "*" * word.length }
```

But that's about it :)

Of course, there are also other ways to go about this, for instance:

```
puts gets.chomp.gsub(/\S/, "*").gsub(/\s+/, "\n")
```

Not that that's necessarily any better.

Comment: Yup, not a lot of code to comment on, it was too easy of a problem :) (p.s. I find that regexes make this piece of code less clear)

Comment: @Caridorc Yeah, as mentioned, it's not better, just different. Personally, I'm quite fond of regexes, but you're right; in this case there's no need. I kind of like that there's no need to split and join - the string remains a string throughout. But that's about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to just 'puts' this at the end, you don't need the join, as `puts` will automatically print each array element on its own line.

```
puts gets.chomp.split.map{|word| '*' * word.length}
```

An alternative way of doing this is with `tr`:

```
puts gets.chomp.split.map{|word| word.tr '^ ', '*'}
```

The arguments to `tr` say replace all non-space chars (`'^ '`) with `'*'`.

Because `tr` works on the string as a whole, you can factor out the `map`:

```
puts gets.chomp.tr('^ ', '*').split
```